# Parsing String in a particular format - <Username>/<Password>@<Host>

Tags: java, string

I have Unix machine connection details in one String as

> `<UserName>/Password@<Host>/<IP>.`

what is the best way to fetch UserName, password and host from this string?

Comment: I have Unix machine connection details in one String as Username/Password@Host. what is the best way to fetch UserName, password and host from this string?

Comment: String userName = connString.substring(0, connString.lastIndexOf("/"));
String password = connString.substring(connString.lastIndexOf("/"), connString.lastIndexOf("@"));
String host = connString.substring(connString.lastIndexOf("@"), connString.length()-1);

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Answer is written on my understanding of your question if you want other than this let me know by comments )

```
String value = "<UserName>/Password@<Host>/<IP>";

        String[] result = value.split("/");

        System.out.println("Username : "+result[0]);
        System.out.println("Password : "+result[1]);
        System.out.println("Host : "+result[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remark that you should check your string against null and emptyness

```
String[] values = yourString.split("/");
String userName = values[0];
String[] valuesOfSecondPart = values[1].split("@");
String password = valuesOfSecondPart[0];
String hostName = valuesOfSecondPart[1];
```